# The guard has gone beserk (or how do I keep multiple MAPI clients running together?)

Tags: delphi, email, outlook, mapi

I have a standalone program that I am trying to hook into MAPI to send emails automatically using the default system (Outlook for the most part) available.  For the most part, it works quite well, and everything sends fine.  However, after a while, Outlook will start to flip out about my program's accessing the MAPI system, and will start to refuse to show anything until all MAPI users (my program and Outlook) are closed and re-opened.  My best guess at this stage is that I'm not using a proper set of flags when logging in to the MAPI system, though I can't see why.  My current set is MAPI_ALLOW_OTHERS, MAPI_EXTENDED, and MAPI_USE_DEFAULT.  Can anyone suggest a different combination that lets Outlook continue to ignore me, and keep the guard placated?  Thanks.

Comment: Does your function call fail? What status code do you get? What is the exact text of the error message? Do you get similar behavior when using something other than Outlook?

Comment: Are you using (Extended) Mapi or are you automating Outlook? What os and what version of Exchange and (ms)mapi32.dll are you running?

Comment: Are you releasing your outlook objects?

Comment: No error message from my code, trying to get the message from Outlook.  Using Extended MAPI, version 1.0.2536.0 with MAPI version 5.5.2174.0.  I don't know Exchange version.  All MAPI objects calling release and free code.

Comment: Hard to tell anything without showing some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced something similar a while back and was able to work around it by centralizing all of my extended MAPI calls from a single point of entry, and added a queue to insure that only one MAPI event from my application was occurring at any point in time.